# OSError(2, 'No such file or directory') when using SublimeREPL and SML on Mac

Tags: sublimetext2, sml, sublimerepl

I'm trying to use SublimeREPL with ST2 and SML on my mac. However, whenever I click on Tools > SublimeREPL > SML, it throws the following error:

OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')

sml is currently already in my PATH, so I'm confused as to why this would be happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration in SublimeREPL might be wrong. You can follow the steps from [this blog](http://developerinmotion.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/sublime-text-2-and-sml/) to set up your SublimeREPL for SML. Read [this](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), if you want to know more about SublimeREPL.